# typeahead functionality gives suggestions even after clearing the search input

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I am using the zomato api to build an angular app where the users search for restaurants after giving a location in the searchbox.

I tried to implement a typeahead without using any libraries. The problem is that after even after clearing out the search input I get suggestions .

**screenshots**

[image: empty searchbox giving suggestions]

[image: normal]

Here's the  component and service files.

**Component file**

```
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {    
  results ;

  locations =[];

  queryField : FormControl = new FormControl();

  constructor(private zomato : ZomatoService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.queryField.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(800),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((query)=>

        this.zomato.getLocations(query)

    )
    ).subscribe(

     response =>{
      this.results = response;
     // console.log(this.results.location_suggestions);
     this.locations = this.results.location_suggestions;
    }    
    );    
  }
```

**service file**

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders( ).set("user-key","76b921cfd73b8312cb243fe4185c65cc");

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ZomatoService {

  public baseUrl = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/";

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  getLocations(location){          
      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "locations?query=" + location+"&count=10",{headers});    
  }

  getLocation_Details(entityId , entityType){

    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + "location_details?entity_id=" + entityId + "&entity_type=" + entityType,{headers});

  }    
}
```

Comment: you are not clearing you location array when the search string is empty. Add an if condition to check if the `query === ''` then set `this.location = []`

Comment: Can a conditional be used within the pipe()?

Comment: yes you can, use "map" or "do" operator.

Comment: I couldn't get any examples for conditional using tap i.e do ,or map operators.I tried this and it worked                                                               
        switchMap(query=> query!==' '
      
        ?this.zomato.getLocations(query)
        :this.locations=[]
       )                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                           
  Is it a good practise?